# General solution of $x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=x\ln x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=x\ln x$ .

**Attempt :**

With $x=e^z$, then the equation becomes :
$$[D(D-1)+D-1]y=ze^z$$

This complementary function comes from 
$$m(m-1)+m-1=m^2-1=0$$

then $m=1$ and $m=-1$
which gives
$$y_c=c_1e^z+c_2e^{-z}$$
For $g(D)ze^z=0, g(D)$ must be ${(D-1)^2}$. The characteristic is the then
$$(m^\prime-1)=0$$
then get $m^\prime=1,1$
. Therefore the particular solution is of the form :
$$y_p=c_3ze^z+c_4z^2e^z$$

Substituting it back in the differential equation

$$[D(D-1)+D-1](c_3ze^z+c_4z^2e^z)=ze^z$$

I am a bit confused how to find the value of $c_3$ and $c_4$. Any help ?

Comment: Simplify that last expression, and see what $c_3$ and $c_4$ have to be to make the left side equal to the right side.

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivatives of $y_p$ and plugging the into the ODE?

Comment: yes, but still not know clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the post, I had the feeling that making $x=e^z$ was complicating something.

I think that I would have started using $y=\frac z x$ which makes the equation to be
$$x z''-z'=x\log(x)$$ Now, reduction of order $p=z'$ gives
$$x p' -p = x \log(x)$$ The homogeneous equation $x p' -p=0$ gives $p=C x$ and the variation of parameters leads to 
$$x^2 C'=x \log(x)\implies C'=\frac {\log(x)}x\implies C=\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(x)+c_1$$ So, we end with
$$z'=p=\frac{1}{2}x\log ^2(x)+c_1 x$$ which does not make too much problems using integration by parts
$$z=\left(\frac{c_1}{2}+\frac 18\right)x^2+\frac{1}{4} x^2 \log ^2(x)-\frac{1}{4} x^2 \log (x)+c_2$$ In other words
$$y=\frac z x=c_1 x+\frac{1}{4} x \log ^2(x)-\frac{1}{4} x\log (x)+\frac{c_2} x$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us make the transformation  $x=e^t$. We get
$$y'-y=te^t.$$
Particular solution we find in form
$$y_p=t(At+B)e^t$$
We find 
$$A=\frac14,\quad B=-\frac14.$$
Then
$$y=C_1e^t+C_2e^{-t}+\frac{(t^2-t)e^t}{4}.$$
After substitution $\;t=\ln x\;$  final solution is
$$y=C_1x+\frac{C_2}{x}+\frac{x(\ln^2x-\ln x)}{4}.$$